# run java class not found

Tags: java, bash, sh

I tried to run java application on ubuntu using .sh file. I compiled successfully all files but when I run the sh file, it said that it couldn't find the main class named PaxosAgent
sh file:

```
for Agentid in `seq 1 5`;
do
echo $Agentid
java -cp target/classes:../../lib/cafe.jar:target/ddspaxos.jar
paxosdds.PaxosAgent $Agentid
done
```

This is the error:
./run_paxosagent.sh: 16: ./run_paxosagent.sh: paxosdds.PaxosAgent: not found

I verified that jar file exists in the right location which is target/ddspaxos.jar and also the name of the package:(
any help please.

Comment: If run run "jar -t target/ddspaxos.jar" from within the same directory, what is the listing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have split the command over multiple lines. The shell script will treat each line as a separate command. You need to put the command all on one line or use `\` to say that a newline is not the end of the command. eg.

```
java -cp target/classes:../../lib/cafe.jar:target/ddspaxos.jar \
    paxosdds.PaxosAgent $Agentid
```

Comment: ok i did, i like to know how i can show every instance of the execution in one console terminal view, every   paxosdds.PaxosAgent $Agentid in one console

Answer (score 0):

Not sure:

```
for Agentid in `seq 1 5`;
do
echo $Agentid
java -cp target/classes:../../lib/cafe.jar:target/ddspaxos.jar
cd "your/path/to/the/jar"paxosdds.PaxosAgent $Agentid
done
```